# sendkeys command causing exception in selenium webdriver on IOS safari

Tags: ios, selenium, safari

I have been trying to run some sample Remote WebDriver tests on the Safari browser on the IOS Simulator 7.0 (IPhone) but my tests give an exception every time I try to type in values on a text box. Just trying to use the example from iosdriver

```
 DesiredCapabilities safari = IOSCapabilities.iphone("Safari");
    RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://<someip>:4444/wd/hub"), safari);

    driver.get("http://hp.mobileweb.ebay.co.uk/home");
    WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.id("srchDv"));
    search.sendKeys("ipod");
    search.submit();
```

gives me the exception

a "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: cannot find element for criteria :{"AND":[{"l10n":"none","expected":"UIAElement","matching":"exact","method":"type"},{"l10n":"none","expected":"Address","matching":"exact","method":"name"}" . 
    Anyone else  run into this? It is identifying the element but typing in values fail..It works fine when I try it on firefox on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but am familiar with selenium webdriver..

Are you sure that the id for "search "  --- ('srchDv') actually exists on the page you are trying to automate?

if so

i would then look into the UIA -Element Hierarchy / Accessibility [link to UIA Element Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementClassReference/UIAElement/UIAElement.html)

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You have an incorrect selector.  The page you are automating does not have an id `srchDv`.  If you are getting the search box, then you need to use:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("gh-ac")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("gh-ac")).sendKeys("ipod");
```

Also, instead of using submit, personally i would follow the way that your user would commit the action, and that's by clicking the search button.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("gh-btn")).click();
```